# Epub edited in Calibre shows no mistakes but IceCream Ebook Reader show me mistakes

Tags: epub, calibre

I am editing a book with Calibre and it seems perfect with Calibre reader, but when I save it and I open the epub using IceCream it shows me mistakes, I trying to discover why. Any comments? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Open the book with Calibre Editor and click Run check followed by Try
  to correct all fixable errors automatically.
- Download [pagina EPUB-Checker](https://www.pagina.gmbh/produkte/epub-checker/) and check your book with it.

Answer (score 0):

Some read soft (or ereaders) ignore css rules, for example: you can add space after/before of any tag, in ADE you can see it but not in others (that's the reason to use `<p>&nbsp;</p>` to make lines); other one is when you use h3 without text inside (for to many reasons) `<h3> </h3>` some readers ignored it, so you must add a non breaking space inside the h3 tag: `<h3>&nbsp;</h3>`.

I never used IceCream so I don't know where is the problem, try to explain what type of errors or if is a "visual" error.